# Access- using VBA, How to have a field that calculates volume difference between current record and previous record

Tags: vba, ms-access

Table records

```
-----------
ID | Volume
-----------
1  |  10
2  |  15
3  |  28
4  |  10
```

Needed result

```
-----------------------
ID | Volume | VolDiff
-----------------------
1  |  10    |  
2  |  15    |   5
3  |  28    |   13
4  |  10    |  -18
```

I'm looking for a method that clearly referencing previous recordset field if available

like or closed to

VolDiff = rs!Volume - **rs![Volume]-1**

The full code is highly appreciated as long time not using Access.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This should do what you need;

```
Dim sql As String
Dim rst As DAO.Recordset
Dim Vol1 As Long, Vol2 As Long

sql = "SELECT * FROM tblTest ORDER BY ID;"

Set rst = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(sql, dbOpenDynaset)

With rst
    .MoveFirst
    Do Until .EOF
        If Vol1 = 0 Then
            Vol1 = Nz(!Volume, 0)
        Else
            Vol2 = Nz(!Volume, 0)
            .Edit
                !VolDiff = Vol2 - Vol1
            .Update
            Vol1 = Vol2
        End If
        .MoveNext
    Loop
End With
```

If the code works for you please mark this question as answered. Thanks.